# Must click like button before see download link (html or javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, facebook-like

I have a document download link on my website and I want everybody must click like button (facebook page), before see download link using javascript or html.

Comment: That's a very bad to get likes. Everybody could easily click "like", download, then "like" again to remove the like. There's no way for you to hold on to your "like".

Comment: hate this kind of systems, better suggest to like than forcing

Comment: I understand what you said, but I think if everyone doesn't like that, they can  dont click like button.

Comment: Like Gating in any way, shape or form is not allowed by Facebook any more; it is explicitly forbidden. Facebook will remove such fake likes once they discover them, so you better not bother with stuff like this at all to begin with.

Comment: thank for sharing, I will stop using this.